# How do I update elements in a nested array and insert them if they are missing in one query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document that looks somewhat like this:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  trips: [
    { uuid: 1, locations: [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}] },
    { uuid: 2, locations: [{id:4}, {id:5}] }
  ]
}
```

I would like to insert the following data into the document

```
const newTrips = [
  { uuid: 2, locations: [{id:4}, {id:5}, {id: 6}]},
  { uuid: 3, locations: [{id:7}]},
]
```

So for the element `uuid:2` a new item needs to get pushed to the `locations` array, and the element `uuid: 3` need to be inserted into the `trips` array of the document.

After all that the original document should look like this:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  trips: [
    { uuid: 1, locations: [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}] },
    { uuid: 2, locations: [{id:4}, {id:5}, {id:6}] }
    { uuid: 3, locations: [{id:7}] }
  ]
}
```

Can this be done in a single query?

I tried this:

```
newTrips.map(trip => {
      return collection.updateOne(
        { _id: 123, 'trips.uuid': trip.uuid },
        { $set: { 'trips.$.locations': trip.locations } },
      )
})
```

This only works for updating `uuid:2`, but doesn't insert a new entry (`uuid:3`).

adding `{ upsert: true }` to the query just pops out the error:

`The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query`

Any ideas?

---

---

UPDATE:

This works, but it's in two queries.

```
newTrips.map(async trip => {
      
  const res = await collection.updateOne(
    { _id: 123, 'trips.uuid': trip.uuid },
    { $set: { 'trips.$.locations': trip.locations } }
   )

   if(res.matchedCount === 0) {
      await collection.updateOne(
        { _id: 123 },
        { $push: { trips: trip} }
      )
    }
})
```

Comment: find by id-> merge the new trips to the found docs trips -> update? takes 2 queries tho

Comment: idk how about doing it in a single find and update. https://codeshare.io/oQoZwo using a custom js logic to merge ?

Comment: btw in your example there are 2*(no of newTrips) amount of queris. also canot do async code in map

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how the `locations` array should be updated?  You say "pushed" but your code example uses `$set`; you're not pushing just `id:6`; you're overwriting the whole list.  Assuming you want to append, is it a unique append based on key `id`?  Is order of `locations` important?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that shows off the power of the pipeline form of `update`:

```js
newTrips.forEach(function(newtrip) {
    rc = db.foo.updateOne(
        { _id: 123 }, // Just match on id...

        [ // pipeline form!
          // Rebuild trip list by keeping ONLY those existing uuid
          // which are NOT in the newtrip:
          { $set: {
            trips: {$filter: {
                input: '$trips',
                cond: {$ne: ['$$this.uuid',newtrip.uuid]}
            }}  
          }},

          // Now, simply take our newtrip which *always* gets on the
          // list and append the filtered list and name it 'trips' (again):
          { $project: {
              trips: {$concatArrays: [ [newtrip], '$trips' ]}
          }}    
          ]
    );
```

The two stages above are shown broken out for clarity.  Astute observers will note this can be folded into a single stage:

```js
        [
          { $set: {
              trips: {$concatArrays: [ [newtrip], {$filter: {
                  input: '$trips',
                  cond: {$ne: ['$$this.uuid',newtrip.uuid]}
              }}
                                     ]}
          }}
        ]
```

### UPDATED

Working with arrays of arrays and looking for indexes is ungainly using `$reduce`.  Sometimes it is just easier to craft some javascript and pass that to take care of things.  The solution below will properly merge new locations into existing `uuid` trip entries based on the `id` of the `locations`.  It is left as an exercise to further refine if a new location `id` completely overwrites the old or if something like `$mergeObjects` should be used.  The assumption here is that matching on `_id` takes care of the major performance hurdles so using custom Javascript to manipulate `trips` is not so bad.

```js
newTrips.forEach(function(newtrip) {
    rc = db.foo.updateOne(
        { _id: 123 },

        [
            { $set: {
              trips: {$function: {
                  body: function(newtrip,oldtrips) {
                      // oldtrips is complete array of trips, "indexed" by uuid.                 
                      // newtrip is a single object                                              
                      var oldtrips_uuids = oldtrips.map(function(d){return d.uuid});

                      var tx = oldtrips_uuids.indexOf(newtrip.uuid);
                      if(tx == -1) {
                          // Brand new; just add newtrip to oldtrips:                            
                          oldtrips.push(newtrip);
                      } else {
                          // Update to existing trip; must merge!                                
                          var upd_trip = oldtrips[tx]; // a REF into oldtrips                    

                          var oldlocs_ids = upd_trip.locations.map(function(d){return d.id});

                          // Go backwards because splice() will change length...                 
                          for(var i = newtrip.locations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                              var tx = oldlocs_ids.indexOf(newtrip.locations[i].id);
                              if(tx != -1) {
                                  upd_trip.locations.splice(tx,1);
                              }
                          }
                          // Combine remaining old + new locs!                                   
                          upd_trip.locations = upd_trip.locations.concat(newtrip.locations);
                      }

                      return oldtrips;
                  },
                  args: [ newtrip, '$trips'],
                  lang: "js"
              }}
            }}
        ]
    );
    print(rc);
});
```

Comment: Astute observers would also notice that OP asked to merge locations of matching uuids ;)

Comment: Yup...  Text does say '...a new item needs to get pushed' but the OP code used plain ol' $set which will overwrite, not merge, and said that worked.   I was tricked!  ;-)  Will go back and fix.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Insufficient testing has always been the best tool in dev's arsenal to claim a solution is working. "Works on my PC badge" was coined for a reason. Yet regardless of quality of the question, there are number of interesting problems revolve around manipulations of nested arrays in Mongodb raised on SO.  I don't see much of practical value in packing everything in a single query, it's still an interesting mental exercise.